# Android application and AsyncTask not behaving as expected

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have an Android application which uses an separate class to communicate with the server. This works fine, however when I press the button on the app (which sends the message to the server), the button becomes greyed out and everything kind of hangs until the response is received. What I would rather, is have the app display a ProgressDialog, so that the user can see something is definitely happening (and no just think it's frozen).

I've tried to do this with AsyncTask, but for some reason it doesn't work.

This is the class I'm using to communicate with the server:

```
public class ServerConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public ServerConnection(Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setTitle("Waiting...");
        dialog.setMessage("...on the world to change.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... msg) {
        String response = null;
        try{
            /**
             *
             * Connects to server, sends message to server, waits for and receives a reponse from server
             *
             **/
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

and this is how I'm using it (note that these lines would be called from some method in an Activity):

```
ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(this);
String response = null;
try {
    response = conn.execute("ThisIsAMessageToTheServer").get();
} catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

When I click a button, the short bit of code is executed and a few seconds later, a response is received from the server. So the code is definitely all working as far as communication with server and correct response goes. The only problem, is that the ProgressDialog is never displayed.

I've had a look around Google and every example I've come across seems to work pretty much exactly like this, so I'm not sure what could be causing the problem.

Comment: remove .get() after execute()

Comment: @RiteshGune This definitely makes the dialog work! Is there any way to get "response" back to the Activity without using get()?

Comment: the response obtained in doInBackground will be passed to onPostExecute() of your asynctask. In post execute you can send back the result to your activity using a callback method using interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [Golu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24483882/1554935). And adding to that,
I would suggest you to create the `AsyncTask` in your `activity` only. So that you can do all the UI related operations based on the response obtained in `onPostExecute()` only.

However if you wish to continue with the structure you are having now, then create an interface providing a callback method. Set your activity as the listener and implement the method in activity.

As the response obtained in doInBackground will be passed to onPostExecute() of your asynctask. In post execute you can send back the result to your activity using a callback method using interface.

//Create the interface as follows:

```
public interface OnResponseReceivedListener{
      public void onResponseReceived(String response);
}
```

// Modify your activity code as follows

```
public yourActivity extends Activity implements OnResponseReceivedListener {


    ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(this);
    conn.setResponseListener(this);

    public void onResponseReceived(String response){

     // TODO: do your UI operations based on the response.
    }
}
```

// Modify your AsyncTask as follows.

```
public class ServerConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    OnResponseReceivedListener mListener;

    public void setResponseListener(OnResponseReceivedListener listener){
       mListener = listener;
    }

    // Your rest of the code
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        mListener.onResponseReceived(unused);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }      

}
```

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that after I get the response string, I need to deal with it other stuff according to what the response was. It appears that I may have to do as most are suggesting, and create the AsyncTask within the Activity. The reason I was trying to avoid this, is because multiple activities need to communicate with the server in the exact same way, and I wanted to avoid duplicating too much code.

Comment: I managed to rewrite (more, reorganise) the code to work with callbacks as you suggested. Thanks heaps for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your `.get()`.  `.get` is a blocking call.  This means you won't return to the event loop (the code in the Android Framework that calls `onCreate`, `onPause`, event handlers, `onPostExecute`, `onPreExecute`, etc) until after it returns.   If you don't return to the event loop, you won't ever go into the drawing code, and you won't display the progress dialog.  If you want to show the dialog, you need to rearchitect your app to actually use the task asynchronously.  Side note-  if you're calling `.get()` like that on your UI thread, your entire app will freeze up and look broken.  That's why they forced people to not do network IO on the UI thread in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense. If I don't use get, then how can I get a string response from the doInBackground() method?

Comment: @BSnapZ then you get string value in onPostExcute method.

Answer (score 1):

You are using get method that's why your `ProgressDialog`  dialog not appearing, remove get and try again.

because `get()` method will block your main thread.

So you need to override `onPostExecute()` for result processing.

```
by use use get() in AsycTask, it will become SyancTask again.
```

**EDIT** try this code:

```
public class ServerConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public ServerConnection(Context ctx){
        context = ctx;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setTitle("Waiting...");
        dialog.setMessage("...on the world to change.");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... msg) {
        String response = null;
        try{
            /**
             *
             * Connects to server, sends message to server, waits for and receives a reponse from server
             *
             **/
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    public onPostExecute(String response) {

    dialog.dismiss(); // dismiss dialgo here.
    // preocess your response here.

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get "response" back from onPostExecute() to the activity which called this class?

Comment: Why you are not creating Asyantask in your Activity as Private class, and do all stuff of response in onPostExecute(), because your activity and asyantask and different thread, so how can you stop your activity code running until response will coming from server.

Comment: Because I have several different activities that use the ServerConnection class, and I don't like the thought of copying/pasting the private class between several activities because that is very poor practise.

Comment: Ok no problem you can make it public and pass the context of relative Activity and also pass relative UI object, remember using common thread between multiple Activity is also not good habit. Asyctask is also one kind of thread because at low level its implementing java thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
 @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Waiting...","...on the world to change.",       
true);

        }
```